# Right form events to display modified data and update modified data?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

A simple task: before displaying the form, if `$data->getRole()` starts with `"ROLE_"`, remove this string and display only the rest. When user submit the form, do the opposite: add `"ROLE_"` before the name.

What's the best place to do this? Actually i'm using `PRE_SET_DATA` and `POST_BIND`. **Are these the right events to perform this operation?**

```
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function(DataEvent $event){

        if(is_null($data = $event->getData()) || !$data->getId()) return;

        $data->setRole(strtoupper(preg_replace('/^ROLE_/i', '',
            $data->getRole())));

    });

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_BIND,
        function(DataEvent $event) {

        if(is_null($data = $event->getData()) || !$data->getId()) return;

        $data->setRole('ROLE_' . strtoupper($data->getRole()));

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well reading the role without the prefix "ROLE" is not something I would do using events. As they obsfusicate your workflow, events should be used with care! Working with symfony for some time, I used them once or twice when there was really no other way. All the other times there was a better way.

I would tend to simply add a function getShortRole and setShortRole and use shortRole within your Entity:

```
class MyEntity {
    private $role;

    public function setShortRole($role) {
        $this->role = 'ROLE_' . strtoupper($role);
    }

    public function getShortRole() {
        return strtoupper(preg_replace('/^ROLE_/i', '', $this->role));
    }
}
```

You are saving yourself a lot of trouble working with models instead of events!

A second, more complicated way would be to use a Model which represents the form instead of the Entity and maps the form to the entity. Here is a good article about this [here](http://www.craftitonline.com/2011/07/symfony2-famous-ozmerks-form-model-pattern/)!
I use it myself and it works nice.